# Is there such a thing as expiration date in EXIF datas?

Tags: metadata, exif, exiftool

In the EXIF data, we have such fields as the time the picture was taken, the location it was taken,..

My company use large quantities of photographies.  Due to regulations about private data's, those photographs shall not be used after various time intervals varying for each photo, depending upon various factors known at creation time.

I was wondering if EXIF data contain field for associating a picture with a data until when the picture still legally usable?

In addition, that should be quite cool to associate the picture with a dossier reference and/or an employee identifier.

It is not about enforcing this policy but rather on how to save such a metadata, in a quite inter-operating way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exif has no field for this special purpose. But it has some fields, you could use: For example the manufacturer store some special information in the MakerNote data, so one could use this field for special features.

Another possiblity could be using the field UserComment where one could store the desired information.

However a way more better would be to use the IPTC format where one can store his own information, espacially the dossier reference. I think this would be a more cleaner way than "misusing" existing fields of Exif.

Answer (score 2):

First, a clarification of terms.  EXIF data is a subset of the various groups of Metadata that can be in an image.  It usually contains mostly info about how the image as taken (camera model, settings, etc).  There is also the older IPTC Legacy (IIM) and XMP, which includes the newer IPTC Core standard. What you use depends upon your software, but while IPTC is more commonly supported, the XMP standard is more flexible.  Most Adobe products support XMP well.

I would suggest using the `Instructions` tag (or `SpecialInstructions` under IPTC Legacy tags).  The purpose of that tag is:

> Any of a number of instructions from the provider or creator to the
>   receiver of the image which might include any of the following:
>   embargoes (NewsMagazines OUT) and other restrictions not covered by
>   the "Rights Usage Terms" field; information regarding the original
>   means of capture (scanning notes, colourspace info) or other specific
>   text information that the user may need for accurate reproduction;
>   additional permissions required when publishing; credits for
>   publishing if they exceed the IIM length of the credit field

You might also look over the [IPTC Photo Metadata Standard 2017.1](https://iptc.org/std/photometadata/specification/IPTC-PhotoMetadata) for full details.